# Labels not appearing in x-axis of second graph when using ggarange

Tags: r, ggplot2

this is my first post here, I'm having issues with getting the labels on the x axis of my second plot to show up when using ggarange, but they show up fine when I run them separately in R. Would anyone be able to give me some advice as to how I can fix this? Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

Plot 1

```
species_bias<- ggplot(Obs_Bias,aes(x=Species,y=Observations, fill=Species))+
               geom_boxplot() +
               stat_summary(fun = mean)+
               theme_classic()+
               ggtitle("Species Bias")+
               theme(legend.position = "none")+
               ylab("Relative Abundance")
species_bias
```

Plot 2

```
Abundace_PLOT<- ggplot(Abundance_Errorbar, aes(x=Species, y=Mean,fill=Method)) + 
                 geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
                 geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Mean-SE, ymax=Mean+SE),width=.2, position=position_dodge(0.9)) + 
                 labs(x="Species", y="Relative Abundnace") + 
                 theme_classic() + 
                  ggtitle("Relative Abundance in Plastifauna grouped by Survey Method")
Abundace_PLOT
```

Combined plots on page

```
Species_Bias_ggarange<-ggarrange(species_bias,Abundace_PLOT + rremove("x.text"), labels = c("A","B"), ncol = 2, nrow = 1)
annotate_figure(Species_Bias_ggarange, top=text_grob("Visualizing Species Bias", face="bold",size=14))

Species_Bias_ggarange
```

Comment: What is `rremove("x.text")` for?

Comment: Please add data using `dput`. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Maybe try not to use `rremove("x.text")`, according to informations about this function, it "remove[s] ggplot component from a ggplot" and "`x.text` [removes] x axis texts (x axis tick labels)"

Comment: I would recommend the `patchwork` package for combining ggplots

Comment: Hello, thank you all for your responses! Sorry about the clumsy question format I shall look into those links before posting any questions in future! 
I'm  not very familiar with R so the rremove("x.text") was only in there because it was in the code I found that I thought would be suitable for my graph. I had tried removing it previously but it did not fix my problem. It may be a spacing thing? I'm  not sure.

Comment: I have installed the patchwork package as you suggested @Richard Telford and the same problem has not occured and my graph is looking very pretty and complete, so thank you all for your help. Much appreciated :)